# Unit testing a class with dependency that uses getBean("myService")

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm using a Jackson custom serializer which is known to not support Spring dependency injection so my serializer class is as follows:

```
public class ShippingAddressDataSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ShippingAddressData> {

    /** Jackson serializers don't support Spring dependency injection */
    private CalculatedSettingsService calculatedSettingsService =
            (CalculatedSettingsService) Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("calculatedSettingsService");

    @Override
    public void serialize(ShippingAddressData addressData, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();

        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("id", addressData.getId());

        CalculatedSettings calculatedSettings = getCalculatedSettingsService()
                .getSettingsForCurrentUser(SettingType.REQUIRE_COUNTY);

        if (calculatedSettings.getIsCountyRequired()) {
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("county", addressData.getCounty());

        }

        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }

    public CalculatedSettingsService getCalculatedSettingsService() {
        return calculatedSettingsService;
    }

    public void setCalculatedSettingsService(CalculatedSettingsService calculatedSettingsService) {
        this.calculatedSettingsService = calculatedSettingsService;
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble unit testing this class because I don't know how to provide a mock version of `calculatedSettingsService`.

The unit test keeps trying to startup my application context and I get the below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not activate tenant <<master>> since it has no application context created
```

Comment: Why can't you just call new and instantiate one?  Spring and DI are wonderful, but they don't have to be the answer to every question.  You're testing a component, not DI.  I like to keep my JUnit tests as isolated as possible.  Either create new or use mocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can autowire `JsonSerializer` with Spring. But you have to use [SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html). Just call it in the constructor and Spring should autowire the dependencies.

```
public class ShippingAddressDataSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ShippingAddressData> {

    @Autowired
    private CalculatedSettingsService calculatedSettingsService;

    public ShippingAddressDataSerializer() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Then in tests you would have to prepare the Spring context with mocked dependency so that you can stub it.

Other option when you cannot make it Spring managed Bean is to not use the autowiring and ask for the `CalculatedSettingsService` in the constructor. You have to register your custom serializer anyway, which is probably done in some Spring config file. You can do the wiring manually there. With such constructor the testing would be trivial.

Here is a draft of such config.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(final CalculatedSettingsService calculatedSettingsService) {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(ShippingAddressData.class, new ShippingAddressDataSerializer(calculatedSettingsService));
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        return mapper;
    }

}
```